# How to Run .Bat File in Azure to install java and Gradle to build an dynamic Apk

Tags: azure, batch-file, gradle, apk, jobs

I want to run an Genrate.bat file that will set Java_home and install Gradle.wrapper. This is work in local machine but i want to do that in Azure to run that .bat file. I try the batch concept but its shows error, It cannot install.

error like Access denied, and gradlew not found

my genrate.bat file:

```
echo "Please wait..."
set JAVA_HOME="%cd%\Java\jdk-11"
setx -m JAVA_HOME "%cd%\Java\jdk-11"
gradlew assembleRelease
```

> ERROR: Access to the registry path is denied.
>   'gradlew' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.
>   'gradlew' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

Please suggest me if there is another way to run .bat in Azure.
Thank you.

Comment: Please define "Azure"

Comment: @CSharpRocks I am trying with Azure batch services and i take Application package and that link to task

Comment: Is it the `setx -m` that yields access denied? I would be surprised if Azure batch gives you access to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE.

Comment: @jwdonahue i try using Set only remove that setx -m but its not running.got error like : ERROR: Access to the registry path is denied.
'gradlew' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'gradlew' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.